# How to use transfer JSON data from an ASP.NET MVC view to JavaScript JSON?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I serialized my data to JSON from the controller:

```
// Serialization
string jsonActivities = JsonSerializer.Serialize(ViewUserNotifications);
ModelData.JsonNotifications = jsonActivities;
```

View:

```
@Model.JsonNotifications  

[{"Id":7,"UserSender":10,"UserReciever":4,"UserSenderName":"Maya","UserSenderSurname":"Robertson","UserSenderProfileImage":"88cf1027-eafd-493f-8b9c-add3f6812eb0_64.jpg","Message":"Maya is following you","Seen":true,"Created":"2021-09-04T21:07:50.3294555","Status":3}]
```

I wonder how can I use this Json data with Javascript? I tried like this:

```
<script>
    var data = JSON.parse(@Model.JsonNotifications);
    console.log(data);
</script>
```

However, in the console I got an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: expected property name, got '&'

Any help is appreciated!

Problem solved:

```
var data = @Html.Raw(Model.JsonNotifications);
```

Comment: @mxmissile, I got this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data, when I add quotes

Comment: Use `Html.Raw` to get the unencoded output.  `var data = @Html.Raw(Model.JsonNotifications);`

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to serialize data. remove the serialization code

```
ModelData.Notifications = ViewUserNotifications;

var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.Notifications));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the code to transfer the JSON data from the ASP.NET to a Java script.

```
 var result =  @Html.Raw(Model.JsonNotifications);
 console.log(result);
```